# Controlling address space layout of dynamic loading

Tags: dll, linker, shared-libraries

Is it possible (in *Linux* / *OSX*) to control how shared libraries are mapped in memory after loading?
Is it possible to malloc a contiguous region of memory, and pass that to a routine such as "`dlopen`"?
I do not insist on precise placement of the various segments (`.text`, `.bss`, etc.) within the malloc'd region, but only that all the segments are placed within the malloc'd region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible (in Linux / OSX) to control how shared libraries are mapped in memory after loading?

I don't know much about OSX, so I'll answer only the Linux part.

Not without modifying the dynamic loader, no.

> Is it possible to malloc a contiguous region of memory, and pass that to a routine such as "dlopen"?

`malloc` will not give you page-alignment required for that. `posix_memalign` will, but you will likely be better off just doing direct `mmap(..., MAP_FIXED, ...)`. You are asking for implementation of this [feature request](http://cygwin.com/frysk/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767) (nobody's done it yet).